# Using CSS instead of an image for logo, how do I...?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Ok so above is an image of pretty much what I'm trying to do. You see how the logo has a solid background behind it that reaches to the VERY top of the page (so there's no white at the top)... that's what I'm trying to do.

This is my html for that part:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="divider">
  <h1>NAME / SLOGAN</h1>
  <ul class="underlinemenu">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div> <!-- end divider -->
```

I'm pretty sure I could just add a image and position it there for the wrapper, so my `<h1>` logo would be over it, but I think that would be pretty inefficient.

I mean there's just two solid colors, black and white... so couldn't that be done with CSS?

When I tried to do it I ended up with a "block"... not what I wanted. There was still white at the very top. I want it more to be like, say, someone cut a piece out of the paper (where the black is) if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you post your CSS for the body, wrapper, divider and h1? Otherwise we are all just guessing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure you don't have any padding in the body:

```
body { padding: 0; }
```

This will ensure your content goes all the way to the very top of the window.

Comment: I would expand this even further and say start your code off with: * { margin:0; padding:0; }. I've always found designing to be easier when you're not fighting with the default paddings & margins.

Comment: If there's no padding then something like...

    h1.logo {
    background-color: #000000;
    }

should work?

Comment: @MW2000: correct. @Stargazer712: I wouldn't do `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`, I would use a "proper" [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) file, since the "*" solution can screw up form controls and the like...

Comment: I tried that it didn't work :/. I added `body { padding: 0; }` and then used `<h1 style="color: #FFFFFF" class="logo">NAME / SLOGAN</h1>` and `h1.logo {
background-color: #000000;
}`

This is what happened: http://i33.tinypic.com/i5db2t.png

When I'm trying to do something more like: http://i34.tinypic.com/2agrvyd.png

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if there is any margins or padding for h1, #divider, #wrapper or body. If so, set it to 0px.

Logo can be done using div with set width/height and background-image properties.

Comment: You mean background-color properties? I don't want to use images.

Comment: @MW2000, Well, it is an another way to do this.  h1.logo { background-color: #000000; color:#ffffff} will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There is a global whitespace reset:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The default margins and paddings are removed and you have no unwanted gaps. The only thing to be aware of: you have to style every gap on your site (e.g. for lists , headings, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<h1>LOGO</h1>` for your logo, how about using `<span class="logo">LOGO</span>`

and put this in your CSS file?

```
.logo {
margin:0;
padding:0;
background:black;
color:white;
font-size:2em; }
```

You can add width, height, and display:inline-block too if you want to adjust the logo box size

Comment: ouch. sorry, didn't mean to offend anyone